# Editing effect properties with KeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Trying to edit AKCompressor properties with this:

```
let compressor = AKCompressor()
compressor[KeyPath: \AKCompressor.threshold ] = 3
```

Got this error... 
     Type 'AKCompressor' has no subscript members

Same with other effects. Need to access properties with KeyPath to unify a few effects in one Class

Comment: https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKitArchive/blob/master/Tests/Tests/AKCompressor.swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo,

```
var compressor = AKCompressor()
compressor[keyPath: \AKCompressor.threshold ] = 3
```

Notice, subscript **keyPath** not **KeyPath**

Also, make sure that AKCompressor if is a struct, is var ie. mutable.